# how to display serial no for every record in detail section using telerik report

Tags: telerik

I have a telerik report.The report has 10 records.I want to display a serial no for every record in detail section.I used RowNumber() function but it displaying 1 for all records.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the function [data scope](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/expressions-scope.html) according to your report layout. For example: =[RowNumber("MyParentGroupName")](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/expressions-data-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create a telerik textbox in Details section and give value as "= ColumnNumber()"

then sl.no will come automatically.